# Dell Latitude laptop case seems distorted and closes no more properly - a serious issue?

Tags: dell-latitude, case, distortion

Today I've noticed the case of the Dell Latitude device, about 2 years old, is a little bit distorted so it does not close properly anymore. Possibly this will lead to more dust getting inside?

- Is this a known problem? If yes are there facts what to expect?
- Other potential problems beyond dust problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the chassis is bent, and now when you close the lid there's a gap on one side?

Comment: @spikey_richie yes: see added screenshot.

Comment: The image is quite cropped, but that looks like the bottom of the laptop has come loose, and looks like something may be bulging inside. Is the battery removable? If so, remove that and see if you can re-seat the bottom of the case. Otherwise, take it to a repair shop.